# enable textbox based on checkbox selection on load

Tags: jquery, razor

I have 2 checkbox, where it control enable or disable of the textbox txtProductName. Currently if the checkbox 2 is checked on load the txtProductName is disable however if the checkbox 1 selected on load the txtProductName is still disable where it supposed to enable

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Check1" value="Value1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" style="margin:1em 1em 5px 5px" @(ViewBag.Status == "Yes" ? " checked" : "")/>Yes

<input type="checkbox" id="Check2" value="Value1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" style="margin:1em 1em 5px 5px" @(ViewBag.Status == "No" ? " checked" : "")/>No


@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProductName, new { id = "txtProductName", style = "width: 150px;margin:1.0em 1.5em 5px -10px;height:20px; font-size:12px", @Value = ViewBag.ProductName })



if ($('#Check1 :checked')) {
            $('#txtProductName').removeAttr("disabled");
}
if ($('#Check2 :checked')) {
            $('#txtProductName').attr('disabled', 'disabled').css("backgroundColor", "white");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
if ($('#Check1').is(':checked')){
```

or

```
if ($('#Check1').prop('checked')){
```

instead of

```
if ($('#Check1 :checked')) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if ($('#Check1').is(':checked')){
```

instead of

```
if ($('#Check1 :checked')) {
```